# How to remove string from text

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string that contain numbers separated by the dots e.g: "2.3.19" or "56.3.10", etc

Sometime string might contain text say "33.4.5.6-any-text-here".

How would you strip the non-numeric text from the string leaving just numbers separated by the dots?

I've tried this solution:
`Number(("33.4.5.6any-text-here").match(/\d+$/));` but that returns `0`

Comment: Does the text always follow the first hyphen?

Comment: @Ry- nope the first hyphen is not compulsory, just removed that one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
"33.4.5.6-any-text-here".match(/[0-9.]*/)[0]
```

- `[0-9.]` matches any number 0-9, and the dot (.).
- `*` matches 0 or more of the previous pattern (digit or dot).
- Since `match` always returns an array in this case (when the 'g' flag is not used in the regex) we can safely return the first item of the array (`[0]`).  It always returns an array in this case because we said "zero or more".  Thus, if zero, it matches nothing and returns an empty string if nothing is found.

Comment: can you explain the answer (the regex) ?

Comment: Sure; explanation added.

Comment: what is `[0]` is for?

Comment: To return the first item of the array of matches.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = "33.4.5.6-any-text-here"

let finStr = str.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''); // .replace(/[^\d|^\.]/g, '')

console.log(finStr); // 33.4.5.6
```

Comment: What about `1.2.3.4-text.123.continue.`?

Comment: return "1.2.3.4.123.."

Comment: my decision leaves numbers and dots

Comment: Are you sure this is the wanted result?

Comment: Depending on the task and data, my answer is for those who want to delete everything except some characters.

Comment: @Toto we can use `"1.2.3.4-text.123.continue.".replace(/([\d.]*)(.*)/, '$1')`